# How to set the IP of the Google App Engine and setup GCM?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Just discovered Google App Engine and wondering if there is a way to push message my Android app?

Does Google App Engine have a Java API for Google Cloud Messaging?  Can I set the IP of the Google App Engine and setup GCM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Cloud Messaging in an App Engine app to push messages to your Android app.

See [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) for more information.